# CakePHP: Session is lost after calling an action from a plugin

Tags: php, session, cakephp, upload, uploadify

I have a plugin for uploading files using jquery uploadify. After calling a method from this plugin the session is lost. I'm no longer logged in.

Is there a way to make all the pages from this plugin public? What can cause this behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to preserve your session, pass your session ID over with the uploadify POST data.

Once you have sent that over, reinitiate the session using:

```
$this->Session->id( $this->data['Model']['phpsessid'] );
$this->Session->start();
```

In your `beforeFilter()`;

This will cause your session to pick back up. The reason it broke, is because Flash is an entirely different user agent.

Comment: What I do, is I created a component called 'SessionRescue' that is loaded in app_controller.php. Use the setup/initialization functions in there to init your session. This is a fancy way of doing it, since the components will get processed before your apps beforeFilter.